# How to send/receive nmea string over tcpip/udp

Tags: tcp, udp, gps, nmea

I have a gps receiver, which can send data (using gprs connection) to the server www.example.com.

Now I need something to receive this data (gps nmea string) from www.example.com (probably, to listen to certain port..), parse this information and store it to my database.

I have some knowledge of php and mysql. So, the questions are - Is it possible to be accomplished with php and mysql? If yes, could you please point me to from what I should start? If no, could you please give me some other suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The www in front suggests http. That would mean you would have to run your own webserver. But you probably have to investigate a little how your receiver is going to POST that data. And then, yes you could run some PHP to receive that data.